# fbsdk react native GraphRequestManager posting parameters

Tags: facebook-graph-api, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to use Facebooks post to page feature of the GraphRequest API but I am running intro trouble trying to post child attachments. It says it expects the child attachments field as an array (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/page/feed)
but when I give it in the following format, react native spits out the following error:

```
JSON value '(
        {
        link = "google.com";
        picture = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    }
)' of type NSMutableArray cannot be converted to NSString
```

Code Below:

```
 const postRequestParams = {
            message: {
                string: 'Hi!'
            },
                    child_attachments: {
                                    string: [{link: 'google.com', picture: 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png'}]

        }

    }

    const postRequestConfig = {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        version: 'v2.10',
        parameters: postRequestParams,
        accessToken: pageAccessToken
    }

     new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(new GraphRequest('/' + fb_page_id + '/feed', postRequestConfig,  (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error)
                  //alert('Error Sharing Post to Facebook: ' + error.toString());



                } else {

                  console.log("post ot Fb page was successful")


                }
              })).start()
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or work-around for this?  I posted a potentially related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293576/posting-mp4-to-facebook-using-graphrequest-in-react-native